# sqlite3_step() is quitting the iPhone application while executing inner joins - memory issue

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I've a db file with multiple tables and each table has a minimum of 20k records. Now I'm trying to execute an inner join query in iPhone using sqlite3.

```
SELECT DISTINCT  abc.id, abc.full_name FROM abc INNER JOIN xyz ON abc.id = xyz.id limit 10 ;
sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
   while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        // populating my custom objects
   }
}
```

When I try the same query with tables having less number of rows, the sqlite3_step() command is working fine.

It would be great if someone can put some light on what exactly it is happening while the statement is getting executed. Will the entire tables be loaded into memory before executing the query and if so what could be the max. limit on the number of records in a table while executing an inner join.

When I'm trying to fetch records from a single table with 50k records its working fine without any issues.

Thanks in advance

Sudheer

Comment: What happens inside this loop:    `while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        // populating my custom objects}` ?

Comment: the statement in while loop is not getting executed successfully. The app quits without any kind of crash report or logs. This is happening when we have huge number of rows in each table and when we execute an inner join itself.

Comment: maybe check your result code `RESULT = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL)`, result codes are at http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html

Comment: Hi megger, the result code is coming as expected (SQLITE_OK). The only issue is with sqlite3_step() function when we execute an inner join with tables having huge number of records (around 30k records). I want to know what exactly it happens while execute the statement. Will it load all the records of all tables to memory? and even the comparison might also taken a lot of time due to huge no. of records in all the tables.

Comment: Try executing the same statement from the command line, debug it there. Do you have indexes on the columns you are using for joins?